# Issue when inserting/updating many documents at once with Mongo/Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hadoop

I have a Java/Spring web service that is launching and monitoring jobs on Hadoop. Whenever a job completes, I insert a document into Mongo, as well as update any related documents (usually about 2 or 3 more). If I'm running one job at a time, everything works great. However, when I'm running 20 jobs at once and multiple are trying to do their insert/update, some documents are just simply not getting inserted.

I've tried to read up on locking with Mongo and it sounds like this should be taken care of without me having to do anything, but its not currently working as intended.

I realize this is a broad question, but I'm just trying to get pointed in the right direction on what could be an issue and what I could look into further. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/ for now and see if you can find any connection to your problem and then may be you can update your post accordingly.

Comment: you can add some code. maybe you use same ids twice or smth similar